# What does "legal vehicles" mean here?

Tags: meaning, meaning-in-context

I used this link but i didn't get the meaning of "vehicle" in this sentence.
https://www.oxfordlearnersdictionaries.com/definition/english/vehicle?q=vehicle

> The checks consisted of finding out whether one or more subsidiaries of the corporate group is listed on the Financial Secrecy Index (a system that ranks jurisdictions according to the secrecy of their offshore activities); seeing whether the group has participated in any financial scandals; looking to see whether the group has published its most recent accounts; asking whether the group has published information on who the beneficial owners are of all its **legal vehicles**; and requesting to see whether the group has committed to employee protection.

Source: https://www.cnbc.com/2020/05/19/coronavirus-eu-countries-deny-bailouts-to-firms-linked-to-tax-havens.html

Comment: https://www.investopedia.com/terms/i/investmentvehicle.asp

Comment: Please see [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/vehicle) meaning ***4** A privately controlled company through which an individual or organization conducts a particular kind of business, especially investment.*